# High request Low impression on Admob ads

Tags: ios, app-store, admob

I made a game for ios and I'm using Admob ads. I think there is a problem about impressions. Every 100 request there are just 50 impressions. In my opinion these impressions is too low. Is it normal? Here is link of my game if you wants to check. [Randerball](https://appsto.re/us/wUPabb.i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use multiple ad networks as Facebook Ads + Admob + Revmob + ... When Admob load fail, in the delegate `- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error,` you should load others ads

Comment: Should I add new code in my project for new ad network? Or can I just add new ad source to admob for mediation? Is  this adding new source enough?

Comment: You can use admob mediation. Alternative, you can ad Facebook Ads SDK to your project. And in `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`of Admob, load Facebook Ads and show it. Currently, Facebook Ads has eCPM > Admob eCPM, but fill rate less than of Admob.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advices